# Who was Rav Moshe Margolis's Rav?

Tags: rabbis, mesorah-tradition, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

I'm currently making a Mesorah chart (I know there are some out there, I just wanted to do it myself). I've gotten all the way back to the Vilna Gaon's Rav, Rav Moshe Margolis, but I can't find any sources as to who his Rav was.

If anybody has any information out there about who his Rav was, I'd really appreciate it. Please cite all sources.

Comment: See the first paragraph on [this page](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36620&st=&pgnum=64), which casts doubt on the idea that the Vilna Gaon was a student of the *P'nei Moshe*.

Comment: i learned a while ago that Gra learned under the Shaagas aryeh

Comment: this Russian source (http://toldot.ru/tora/articles/articles_738.html, written by a known *talmid chacham* in the Russian world) claims he learned from Pnei Moshe until the age of 9

Comment: @gt6989b this is a well known legend. The question is whether it is true.

Comment: The Gaon’s sons wrote in their [intro. to the Shulchan Aruch](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14212&st=&pgnum=5) that their father “learned by a rebbi only until six years old”. They don’t mention R. Margolios once. That’s pretty telling, coming from the Gaon’s own sons.